# SQL COUNT occurrence of column value on LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, count

I have seem similar questions on here but none of the answers seem to fit what I am looking for-

Say I have one table like so:

| AssignedTo | DeptID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 5001 | Elementary |
| Bob | 5002 | Middle |
| Bob | 5003 | Elementary |
| Jill | 5004 | High |
| Bob | 5005 | High |
| Bob | 5006 | High |

and another like so:

| User | Telephone | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 111-222-3333 | 111 South Lane |
| Bob | 222-111-3333 | 222 North Drive |
| Jill | 333-222-1111 | 555 Highway |

I want to output the second table with a left join on the first table with the total number of 'Type' (elementary, middle,high) by each assigned user, so it would like something like:

| User | Telephone | Total Elementary | Total Middle | Total High |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 111-222-3333 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Bob | 222-111-3333 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Jill | 333-222-1111 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I've tried `--Count(case when <table>.[type] = 'Elementary' then 1 else 0 end) AS ElementaryCount,` but this just gets me the entire table, not by the user on the left join.

Anyone have any ideas how I can go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### next time

Please follow the advice in this Q&A:

- [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Particularly to prepare the data as create table and insert statements to stage it for easy consumption by people trying to help you in their free time.

```
CREATE TABLE
    #assignments
(
    AssignedTo varchar(10),
    DeptID integer,
    [Type] varchar(10)
);

INSERT
    #assignments
(
    AssignedTo,
    DeptID,
    [Type]
)
SELECT
    x.AssignedTo, 
    x.DeptID, 
    x.Type
FROM 
(
    VALUES
    ('Mary', 5001, 'Elementary'),
    ('Bob',  5002, 'Middle'),
    ('Bob',  5003, 'Elementary'),
    ('Jill', 5004, 'High'),
    ('Bob',  5005, 'High'),
    ('Bob',  5006, 'High')
) AS x (AssignedTo, DeptID, [Type]);

CREATE TABLE
    #users
(
    [User] varchar(10), 
    Telephone varchar(12),
    Address varchar(20)
);

INSERT
    #users
(
    [User],
    Telephone,
    Address
)
SELECT
    x.[User], 
    x.Telephone, 
    x.Address
FROM
(
VALUES
    ('Mary', '111-222-3333', '111 South Lane'),
    ('Bob',  '222-111-3333', '222 North Drive'),
    ('Jill', '333-222-1111', '555 Highway')
) AS x ([User], Telephone, Address);
```

Now add rows for Users that don't have any Assignments:

```
INSERT
    #users
(
    [User],
    Telephone,
    Address
)
SELECT
    x.[User], 
    x.Telephone, 
    x.Address
FROM
(
VALUES
    ('E-Cores', '000-000-0000', '1 Slow Street'),
    ('P-Cores', '999-999-9999', '1 Fast Street')
) AS x ([User], Telephone, Address);
```

### conditional

This should get you what you want, using `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

```
SELECT
    u.[User],  
    u.Telephone,
    TotalElementary = 
        SUM
        (
            CASE 
                a.Type
                WHEN 'Elementary'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ),
    TotalMiddle = 
        SUM
        (
            CASE 
                a.Type
                WHEN 'Middle'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ),
    TotalHigh = 
        SUM
        (
            CASE 
                a.Type
                WHEN 'High'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
FROM #users AS u
LEFT JOIN #assignments AS a
    ON u.[User] = a.AssignedTo
GROUP BY 
    u.[User], 
    u.Telephone;
```

### results

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
|  User   |  Telephone   | TotalElementary | TotalMiddle | TotalHigh |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| E-Cores | 000-000-0000 |               0 |           0 |         0 |
| Mary    | 111-222-3333 |               1 |           0 |         0 |
| Bob     | 222-111-3333 |               1 |           1 |         2 |
| Jill    | 333-222-1111 |               0 |           0 |         1 |
| P-Cores | 999-999-9999 |               0 |           0 |         0 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
```